# Why is GNU shred faster than dd when filling a drive with random data?

Tags: linux, dd, random-number-generator, shred

While securely erasing a hard drive before decommissioning I noticed, that `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda` takes nearly a whole day, whereas `shred -vf -n 1 /dev/sda` only takes a couple of hours with the same computer and the same drive.

How is this possible? I guess that the bottleneck is the limited output of `/dev/urandom`. Does shred use some a pseudorandomness generator that is less random and only sufficient for it's single purpose (i.e. more efficient) than `urandom`?

Comment: Note that the best option for erasing drives, especially ssd drives, is the SATA secure erase command. Any other option - barring destruction - will fail. Its much faster too, and may just take seconds on an SSD.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Shred [uses an internal pseudorandom generator](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Random-sources.html#Random-sources)

> By default these commands use an internal pseudorandom generator
>   initialized by a small amount of entropy, but can be directed to use
>   an external source with the --random-source=file option. An error is
>   reported if file does not contain enough bytes.
>
> For example, the device file **/dev/urandom** could be used as the source
>   of random data. Typically, this device gathers environmental noise
>   from device drivers and other sources into an entropy pool, and uses
>   the pool to generate random bits. If the pool is short of data, the
>   device reuses the internal pool to produce more bits, using a
>   cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator. But be aware
>   that this device is not designed for bulk random data generation and
>   **is relatively slow**.

I'm not persuaded that random data is any more effective than [a single pass](http://www.anti-forensics.com/disk-wiping-one-pass-is-enough) of [zeroes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_remanence#Feasibility_of_recovering_overwritten_data) (or any other byte value) at obscuring prior contents.

To securely decommission a drive, I use a big magnet and a large hammer.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it would be caused rather by `dd` using smaller chunks to write the data. Try `dd if=... of=... bs=(1<<20)` to see if it performs better.

Comment: I'll try that on the next occasion and post the results.

Comment: +1 Default `dd` block size is 512. It performed way below disk limits on my computer.

Comment: /dev/urandom is likely plenty fast - the dd block size is almost certianly the issue.

Comment: Once you increase the block size it seems like `/dev/urandom` can become a bottleneck - I'm testing some SSD drives over USB 3.0 and with the same `dd` command I get 326 MB/s for `if=/dev/zero` but only 12.8 MB/s for `if=/dev/urandom`