# How to write a hard disk filling file with shred to erase disk data?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, shred

It is possible to obtain the searched result in the following two known but not searched ways:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/mounted/partition/my_file.txt bs=64k
```

But would it be possible to use to use [`shred`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/shred) as a source for zeros or random data and write this as a file to a hard disk?

Shred can be used in the following way to create a data stream, but not write it to a file yet.

```
sudo shred -n 0 -v -z /dev/sdXX
```

Perhaps its possible to write a file with `shred` in a way like this:

```
sudo shred -n 0 -v -z > my_file.txt
```

I’m interested asking this question for these reasons:

- I like to compare the speed of different ways to fill a disk by a file. It can be, useing as source `/dev/zero` have the 25x speed than `/dev/urandom`, `srandom` is up to 150x faster than `/dev/urandom`. Perhaps using shred as source, will be much faster than `/dev/urandom` too?

  See follow: [Why is GNU shred faster than dd when filling a drive with random data?](https://superuser.com/questions/418298/why-is-gnu-shred-faster-than-dd-when-filling-a-drive-with-random-data?rq=1)
- `srandom` is still not available on some systems, but shred looks available to most systems. So it can possibly used as a fast alternative to `/dev/zero` and `/dev/urandom`

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)? Why do you want to use `shred` this way?

Comment: (1) Writing to `/dev/sdXX` has nothing to do with any filesystem. If for any reason writing to `/dev/sdXX` does not guarantee overwriting all the data then writing to the filesystem there also cannot guarantee. (2) `shred -n 0 -z` writes zeros, not random data; so don't compare to solutions using `urandom`, compare to solutions using `/dev/zero`.

Comment: No offense, but it's hard to understand what you want to do. If you want to fill up the entire partition with zeros, then your `shred` command will do (`cat /dev/zero > /dev/sda1` would do as well). If this is not what you want, or if it doesn't work as expected, please explain.

Comment: (3) Most filesystems won't allow you to create a non-sparse file as large as the disk that holds the filesystem. You can create a file at most as large as empty space in the filesystem, which is less. Is this what you want to do? Fill empty space in a *filesystem* with zeros? (4) If so, what is wrong with the `dd` command you posted? Why do you need `shred` for this? (5) Are you aware of slack space? Is slack space not a concern?

Comment: OK, so you first create the file with `cat /dev/zero > myfile`, then you apply the `shred`command to this file. But not only the file won't fill the entire partition (as mentioned by @KamilMaciorowski), but I also don't see the point of shred, then, as the file is already filled up by zeros upon creation.

Comment: I updated the question. Perhaps its more clear now.

Comment: I still don't know why you need `shred` for this. If you didn't use `-n 0 -z`, then it would make some sense (not necessarily a lot of it though). With `-n 0 -z` you tell `shred` to write NUL bytes, which is exactly what `dd if=/dev/zero` or `cat /dev/zero` can do. I can give you a way to create a largest possible file quickly, then you can `shred` this file at will. Is this what you want? I cannot guarantee this will solve whatever problem you're trying to solve, at least until you tell us what your goal really is. Your fixation on `shred` really looks like an XY problem.

Comment: This should be explained in the question body, not in comments. But why do you need to do this *in a filesystem*? I thought you wanted to shred as much of the empty space as possible, while keeping the existing files intact. But in your own answer you create a filesystem anew, as if you didn't care about old data or wanted to shred it; but then you shred in a way that does not guarantee shredding *all* the old data. What is the point? Why not to shred the entire partition?

Comment: For you reference, `openssl enc` can be used to create random data stream (by "encrypting" /dev/zero with a password from e.g. /dev/urandom).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shred` does not care if it writes to a block special file (like `/dev/sdXX` in your example) or to a regular file. This command

```
shred -n 0 -v -z my_file
```

is perfectly valid, although keep in mind that:

- `my_file` must be created beforehand, `shred` will not create it;
- the size of `my_file` matters, `shred` will not expand it.

If you want to `shred` a file that takes whole available space in a filesystem, then you need to create the file as large enough. There are at least three methods (from "smartest" to "dumbest"):

1. If the filesystem supports sparse files, create a sparse file that is at least as large as the free space. It may be bigger. An easy way is to overshoot: there is no need to worry what the exact size should be, create a sparse file that is *larger for sure*. `truncate(1)` is the right tool (e.g. `truncate -s 500G my_file`).

   The sparse file will initially not allocate blocks of the filesystem. Blocks will be allocated during the actual `shred` job, the file will get less and less sparse, up to the specified size. If the size cannot fit into the filesystem then you will get `no space left`. In fact you want to get this error, you want to allocate as many blocks as you can.

   This method will give you a similar result to the `dd` method (which also ends with `no space left`).
2. Create a non-sparse file in a smart way. If the filesystem supports the `fallocate(2)` system call, use `fallocate(1)` to create a file as big as possible. An easy way is to overshoot with the size and get `no space left`, the file should be created with the biggest possible size. (E.g. `fallocate -l 500G my_file`.)

   Thanks to the support for `fallocate(2)`, blocks will be allocated by marking them as uninitialized, without actual IO to the data blocks. Data will be written when you `shred` later.
3. Crate a non-sparse file in a dumb way. If the filesystem does not support `fallocate(2)`, you can still use `fallocate(1)` to create a file. Without support for `fallocate(2)`, data blocks will be filled with zeros. This will take time, will already do what you want your `shred -z` to do.

   If your goal is only to see how fast `shred` alone is, creating a test file even with this method will allow you to test `shred` later anyway. If your goal is to write zeros once, then you don't need `shred` *in this case* because sole `fallocate(1)` does the job.

Notes:

- `truncate(1)` vs `fallocate(1)`. The former tries to create a sparse-file, the latter tries to create a non-sparse file.

  If the filesystem does not support sparse files, `truncate(1)` should work similarly to `fallocate(1)`. This means you can use `truncate(1)` and the file will be created in the smartest possible way. Frankly the 2nd method is not really less smart than the 1st, because ultimately `shred` will make the file non-sparse anyway. This means you can as well use `fallocate(1)` instead of `truncate(1)`, regardless if your filesystem supports sparse files or not.
- If the filesystem uses compression, it may be hard to "fill it" with zeros. A long stream of zeros compresses extremely well.
- If the underlying block device for the filesystem is an SSD or if the filesystem exists in a regular file which in turn belongs to a filesystem that supports sparse files, then `fstrim` is probably the fastest way to "write" zeros to unused blocks of the filesystem. (Note: this may or may not zero out *all* the unused blocks.)

Comment: If I create a emty file with no size, does this file filled up to disk filling size by shred -n 0 -v -z my_file ?

Comment: @Alfred.37 I wrote "`shred` will not expand it" and I mean it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, your intention is to write random data to the whole
disk/partition, and your only goal is to measure write speeds.

This can be achieved with `shred` by using the command :

```
shred --random-source=/dev/urandom -n1 /dev/sdX
```

The parameter `-n1` stands for one pass.

The source `/dev/urandom` is a reasonable source of pseudo-random data.
Alternatively, any encrypted file can also be used as source for
reasonable random data.

If your intention is to have a second pass that will set the disk
or partition to zeroes in order to hide the use of `shred`,
add the parameter `--zero`.

References :

- [Securely wipe disk](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Securely_wipe_disk)
- [shred(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/shred)

Comment: It dosnt loooks for me, the follow create a disk filling file: shred --random-source=/dev/urandom -n1 /dev/sdX

Comment: Did you use `sudo`?

Comment: The follow dont consist of any file name: shred --random-source=/dev/urandom -n1 /dev/sdX  What the name of the file which will be created ?